# Pass a closure with function.apply

Tags: javascript

consider a function with parameters:

```
function add1(a, b) { return a + b; }
```

We can call `add1` using for instance `add1.apply(window, [1, 2])` and get the result `3`

---

consider a function using `this`:

```
function add2() { return this.a + this.b; }
```

We can call `add2` using `add2.apply({a: 1, b: 2}, null)` and get the result `3`

---

consider a (not so good) function:

```
function add3() { return a + b; }
```

**Is there any way we can call this function and pass a closure containing values for `a` and `b` ?**

Note that creating `a` and `b` in the global scope is not an acceptable solution (e.g. `window.a=1; window.b=2; add3();` )

Comment: Can you give an example of how you want the function `add3` to be called?

Comment: "*pass a closure*" - that's not what you mean. A [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) is a function with its environment, like `add3` (which closes over `a` and `b`)

Comment: @AmitJoki i'm experimenting a bit with type annotations in coffeescript using some concepts from https://jscategory.wordpress.com/ so the use case is quite special.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C'mon you guys. Javascript is a dynamic language, so pretty much anything is possible:

```
function add3() { return a + b; }

(function notGlobalScope() {
    var a = 1;
    var b = 2;
    var funcBody = "var a="+ a +", b="+ b +";\n"+
        add3.toString() +"\n"+
        "add3()";
    console.log(eval(funcBody));
})()
```

Comment: Yes, you can write a `putInNewScope` function (as long as `toString` is supported), but there's no way to pass values to the free variables in the original function.

Comment: True, but since the function itself is not changed it doesn't matter if it's the original or a copy. Therefore I would say the answer to this question is yes as  he is referring to the function as code not as a particular runtime instance of the function.

Comment: Well, if the original actually was a closure (on *some* of its free variables), it would make a difference :-)

Comment: Again true, but the answer to this particular question still remains that yes it is possible by copying the function :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the idea of declaring arguments as a and b is to have these variables already set in the body of the function. So you don't need to do

```
function add_ab() { 
  var a = arguments[0]; 
  var b = arguments[1];  
  return a + b; 
}
```

or done in Perl style:

```
function add_ab() { 
  var args = Array.slice(arguments); 
  var a = args.shift(); 
  var b = args.shift(); 
  return a + b; 
}
```

Normally if you don't know the number of the arguments, you can just pass one argument of type array so you can add all numbers inside the array.